# Bootstrap Tooltip not showing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I had my tooltip working just fine with the default `$('selector').tooltip('show');`
Then I wanted to get all fancy. It's got to be something obvious but I just can't see it.

**Javascript**

```
initTooltip(
    $element, {'placement': 'bottom', 'title': Messages[$element.id + 'Required']}
);
```

**Javascript:**

```
initTooltip: function($element, options) {
    $('#' + $element.id).tooltip({
        'placement': options.placement,
        'title': options.title
    });
}
```

When I log the params for initTooltip, this is what I am getting (as expected)

**Javascript:**

```
Object {placement: "bottom", title: "Please enter your Last Name."}
```

Everything seems to be in place, I am not getting any errors either. The tooltip itself just doesn't render. It's like I need to call `tooltip.show()` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that fits my needs. My downfall was the "trigger" property. For anyone who comes across this post, here is what I am doing & is working well.

**JavaScript:**

```
initTooltip($element, {'placement': 'bottom', 'title': Messages[$element.id + 'Required']});
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/**
* Renders a tool tip for the given input.
* @param {object} $element | The input element.
* @param {object} options | Display options.
* @returns {void}
* 
*/
initTooltip: function($element, options) {
    $('#' + $element.id).tooltip({
        'placement': options.placement,
        'title': options.title,
        'trigger': 'manual'
    }).on({
        blur: function() {
            $('#' + $element.id).tooltip('show');
        },
        focus: function() {

        }
    });
}
```

I am validating a text input using the `onInputFocusOut` event. When that happens, If there is an error, I show the error, then render the tooltip (above).

Answer (score 0):

Assign all your tooltips a class="ttip" and use this function:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ttop").tooltip({
    placement : 'top'
  });
 });
```

You can see I've made it work on this [project](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/cover.html).